# Attribute error in sending email through smtp in python 3.7

Tags: python, smtp, python-3.7, smtplib

I have hidden id and password in this question. But, gmail password was generated after
turning on 2 step verification and generating an app password.

ERROR--
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'

```
import smtplib

email = "*****@gmail.com"
password = "*****"
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", port=587) as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=email,
                        to_addrs="*****@yahoo.com",
                        msg="Subject:Hello\n\nThis is the body of the email"
                        )
```

Comment: What is the name of the python file you are running?

Comment: @Goku Yeah it was email.py. Looked around on google, and found it creates a circular dependency. I changed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error generally occurs when Python discovers a circular dependency with the `smtplib` module.

If your python script is named `smtplib.py` or `email.py`, Python would try to import your file when it executes the import statement for the `smtplib` library.

As a result, it creates a partially initialized module, and if your script does not have an attribute named smtp, you will run into this error.

**Solution** :

Rename your email sending python script to a name apart from `smtplib.py` or `email.py`